# Why Measurable space with power set is still called Measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

By the standard definition, a measurable space is a tuple (X,F), where X is a set, and F is a sigma algebra on X.

Now we take X as real numbers R, and the power set of X (which is a sigma-algebra) as F.

We know that power set on R contain non-measurable sets, why then such a pair (tuple) would still be called a measurable space?

Comment: The fact that there exist non-measurable sets refers to te Lebesgue measure. But there are all kinds of sigma algebras besides Lebesgue measurable sets and all kinds of measures besides Lebesgue measure.

Comment: It's naming only. The members of $F$ are called 'measurable' with respect to the given measurable space $(X,F)$, and this is a basic (undefined) notion in measure theory. Usually, btw, $F$ is strictly smaller than the power set.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy so, it means that for any given set and any sigma-algebra on that set there is at least one measure, right?

Comment: The two terms "measurable set" and "measurable space" are not the same.  I agree the term "measurable space" is confusing.  Some have proposed use of the term "Borel space" instead, which has its own confusions.

Comment: @IgnatFialkovskiy: It's even better: there is a measure that works for any sigma-algebra, namely the counting measure.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).